# aws cli not honouring default region configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have the default region set in `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
```

However, when I try `describe-instances` command for some specific profile it is failing with the following message:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --profile my_profile
You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".
```

Shouldn't it used the default profile configured in `~/.aws/config` file? What am I missing here?

Output of `aws configure list`:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ******************** shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ******************** shared-credentials-file
    region                us-west-2      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

Output of `aws configure list --profile my_profile`

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                my_profile           manual    --profile
access_key     ******************** shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ******************** shared-credentials-file
    region                <not set>             None    None
```

p.s. new to AWS. pardon me if this is a very basic question.

Comment: what does `aws configure list` print in the region row ?

Comment: @Ersoy added the output in the description.

Comment: what about `aws configure list --profile my_profile` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [named profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html), by default `default` profile is used. Just like you `configure` default, you can/need to configure your profile.

```
aws configure --profile my_profile
```

It will prompt you to fill `access key`, `secret access key`, `AWS Region`, and `output format` as it is stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)

> You can create additional configurations that you can refer to with a name by specifying the --profile option and assigning a name. The following example creates a profile named produser. You can specify credentials from a completely different account and Region than the other profiles.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that the default region config should be applicable to all the profiles.

Comment: @vatsalmevada you are welcome. it is useful for managing multiple accounts under different profiles.

Comment: thanks it works, i have my sso with nothing except aws region and it works